# Concatenate a list of strings to one string haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a list of strings (see below) how do I concatenate these strings into one list containing one string.

```
["hello","stack","overflow"]
```

to

```
["hellostackoverflow"]
```

I am just allowed to import Data.Char and Data.List

Comment: Do you want the result to be one string or a list containing one string?

Comment: `concat` - if you want it in a list use `return . concat` (don't forget the type annotation if you try it in GHCi: `return . concat $ ["hello","stack","overflow"] :: [String]`)

Comment: @Lee I meant a list containing one string.
 thanks, it worked. Post it as an answer so I can accept it :D.

Comment: @downvoter can you explain how I can improve the question

Comment: We're down-voting because you gave no indication of what you did to solve the problem on your own, and it's not interesting enough to excite us.

Comment: Wrapping the result back into a list is a bit weird, since it throws away the knowledge that there's only one result string.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider each string in a list as a list of characters

```
["hello","stack","overflow"] :: [[Char]]
```

Concatenation is a process of connecting several lists into one. It must have a following type:

```
concat :: [[a]] -> [a]
```

If you will have such a function, you'll get a half of job done. You are looking for a way to get

```
["hellostackoverflow"]
```

as a result of concatenation. Once again, look at it's type:

```
["hellostackoverflow"] :: [[Char]]
```

It is the same type as you had at the beginning except that there is only one element in a list. So now you need a function which puts something into a list. It must have a type

```
putToList :: a -> [a]
```

Once you'll have both `concat` and `putToList` functions, your solution will be almost ready. Last thing you need to do is to compose it like that:

```
myConcatenation = putToList . concat
```

---

I suggest you to use [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) to search existing function by it's type.

Comment: @Kwarrtz it is too low level. Better to use [pure](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:pure) or [return](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:return).

Comment: Why would using a "low level" function be disadvantageous here?

Comment: @Kwarrtz not sure why I said it's too low level at that time. I have probably read somewhere about lists and that their raw functions must be avoided in favor of generic code. I think both solutions are fine in educational purposes. Anyway, I would go with `pure` because I would be too lazy to write `(:[])`. Plus, it's well defined name. I won't need to think about what does it do once I'll come back to the code after a while. Sorry for delayed answer :)

Answer (score 6):

```hs
concat ["hello","stack","overflow"] -- => "hellostackoverflow"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the list monad to reduce the list to a single string, then re-wrap the result in a list.

```
> [["hello", "stack", "overflow"] >>= id]
["hellostackoverflow"]
```

The preceding avoids explicitly use of `Control.Monad.join`:

```
> import Control.Monad
> [join ["hello", "stack", "overflow"]
["hellostackoverflow"]
```

Comment: `xs >>= id` and `join xs` are equivelent to `concat xs`. Why needlessly complicate a simple operation?

Comment: @Kwarrtz this answer shows how to achive the goal using monadic properties of `[]`. It's not about how to make it more complicated.